# Migrating a webfrom asp.net appllication to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, migration

I have been working on a CMS project based on asp.net webforms. It follows simple multitier architecture and contains a single aspx page where the usercontrols (ascx) in the form of modules are loaded dynamically.

Now a lot of clients are demanding it in MVC. I m wondering if it is feasible to seamlessly convert it into MVC. Is the hype just because MVC is the new paradigm for dot not or is it because it does yield substantial benefits?

What is the easiest way to migrate from WebForms to MVC?

Comment: Here is a brief discussion on this question  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571315/how-would-you-sprinkle-in-asp-net-mvc-into-an-existing-web-site-project

Answer (score 3):

You can always convert your existing ASP.NET web application project to include MVC and make it as a hybrid application. Scott Hanselman wrote a [simple post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) to demonstrate how to do that.

If you are trying to add MVC to existing ASP.NET web application, Check out this [link](http://www.techiesweb.net/how-to-get-add-view-add-controller-menus-in-solution-explorer-when-converting-existing-asp-net-web-for-project-to-mvc/). I have scribbled a useful tip there to bring the MVC specific Context menu ( Add Controller/Add View) in the solution explorer.

The below statement is purely personal. (of course both has it's own pros and cons)

***Personally If i start a new project, i will choose MVC over webforms. because i tasted it. It is addictive**. :)* **I think** My MVC projects are much cleaner than webforms ones.